# Probability Generating Function of Zn

Tags: probability, generating-functions

Given the following Probability Generating Function:

#### $G(s)=1-α(1-s)^β$

where <strike>$0≤α≤1$</strike> and $0$ < $ β≤1$.

 
Are we able to derive the Probability Generating Function <strike>$G_n(s)$</strike> of the random variable <strike>$Z_n$</strike> in the usual notation where <strike>$G_n(s)=G(G_{n-1}(s))$</strike> and thus find an expression for <strike>$P(Z_n=0), P(Z_n=1)$</strike>, and <strike>$P(Z_n=2)$</strike>?

I tried finding <strike>$E[Z]$</strike> by findng <strike>$G'(1)$</strike> but ended up with <strike>$αβ(1-s)^{β-1}$</strike>, where <strike>$(1-s)$</strike> will be 0 and <strike>$\beta -1 ≤ 0$</strike> making it undefined.

I was however, able to find the probability of ultimate extinction (treating this as branching process) to be a geoemetric series in power of <strike>$\alpha$</strike> into:

$G_n(0) = 1-\alpha ^{\frac{1- \beta ^n}{1-\beta}}$

But I'm not sure how that would be helpful in determining the PGF of <strike>$Z_n$</strike> and the respective probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using induction on $n$, you easily get $G_n(s)=1-\alpha^{(1-\beta^n)/(1-\beta)}(1-s)^{\beta^n}$ (reading $1-\alpha^n(1-s)$ for $\beta=1$). As for the expected values, you've got a correct result; these don't exist (i.e. are $\infty$) if $\beta<1$.